# Ruby boolean operator precedence, different behaviours

Tags: ruby

Why does precedence behave differently in the following code :

```
a = true or true and false

if a then
  puts "Foo"
end

if true or true and false then
  puts "Quux"
end
```

This only prints "Foo" and not "Quux".

```
E:\Home>ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]

E:\Home>ruby test.rb
Foo
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operator  `=` has precedence over `and` and `or` (see [there](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence) for instance). So in your first statement,

```
a = true
```

is evaluated before the rest. Hence, you set `a` to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the operator precedence

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence

The order of evaluation is like this

```
(((a = true) or true) and false)
# a = true

if (true or true) and false then
# equivalent to
if true and false then
```

To get a more natural behaviour, use `&&` and `||`.

Answer (score 0):

see here

```
2 and 7
#=> 7
2 or 7
#=> 2
2 or 7 and 12
#=> 12
2 or 7 or 12
#=> 2
2 or 7 and 12 or 10
#=> 12
true and true and false
#=> false
true or true or false
#=> true
true and true or false
#=> true
true or true and false
#=> false
true or true and false and true
#=> false
```

***Summary :***

(a) when you will use in an expression with only `and` operator value of the expression is always the last operand and the reverse is true for expression having only `or` operator.In case of Boolean the full expression will be evaluated.

(b) When an expression will have `and` and `or` mixed, evaluation will continue till the last `and` and its **`ROH`** operand will be the value of the expression(in case of `Boolean` last `and` RHO,LHO will be evaluated,after that result will be produced as Boolean operation rule.

*Applying the rule of (b)*

below code works:

```
if true or true and false then
  puts "Quux"
end
#=> nil

a = true or true and false
#=> false

if a then
  puts "Foo"
 end
#Foo
#=> nil
```

Below code outputs `Foo` due to the precedence of `=` over `and`,`or`.

The expression `a = true or true and false` evaluates as follows applying the rule (b)

```
a = true or true and false
         ||
(a = true) or true and false
         ||
    true and false
         ||
       false
```

*One more good application of rule (b)*

```
if 2 and 3 or nil
 p "hi"
end
#=> "hi"

if 2 or 3 and nil
 p "hello"
end
#nothing printed
```