# Why does variable = true AND false result in a value of true in a rails model but not in the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In order to determine if a photo matched a specified aspect ratio I used this:

```
exif2 = EXIFR::JPEG.new(photo.queued_for_write[:medium].path)
self.featured = exif2.width == 1250 and exif2.height == 833
```

However this returned true if just the width was 1250 but the height was any value. Running this exact command in the rails console returns false if exif2.height is not 833. Changing it to the if statement below works, however

```
if exif2.width == 1250 and exif2.height == 833
  self.featured = true
else
  self.featured = false
end
```

I don't understand why and I'm trying to learn rails so I think it would be useful for me to understand it.

Comment: possible duplicate [Ruby boolean operator precedence, different behaviours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465421/ruby-boolean-operator-precedence-different-behaviours): it's because `=` has precedence over `and`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Operator precedence, `and` is lower precedence even than `=`

So your first expression is evaluated as

```
( self.featured = exif2.width == 1250 ) and ( exif2.height == 833 )
```

Your conditional is evaluated so

```
if ( exif2.width == 1250 ) and ( exif2.height == 833 )
```

. . . showing that your different answers, although confusing, are not due to any inconsistency

Use `&&` instead of `and` where you can

Comment: Thanks Neil! But why does it work in the rails console? And would I be correct in thinking that

self.featured = ( exif2.width == 1250 and exif2.height == 833 )

would work?
Also what's the advantage of &&?

Comment: The advantage of `&&` is that it has the precedence that you would expect and you never would have needed to ask this question because everything would have worked the way you thought it should.

Comment: @Stuart: I cannot see why you got a different answer in Rails console. Rails changes a lot of Ruby around, but operator precedence is, AFAIK, quite difficult to change. A quick Google shows nothing obvious. If your console session has a history, perhaps you could check, and add an inspect on `exif` just in case it didn't contain quite what you thought during your debug session. It would be quite interesting on SO if it really was different, so worth posting . . .

Comment: Neil, I just started up a new console session and if I just go for something simple like: test = 1==1 and 1==2 it returns false

Comment: Never mind. You're right, if I actually check test it's true. I was just looking at what the overall statement returned

Answer (score 1):

The lesson to learn is to understand operator precedence, to use parenthesis to force the order of operations and not hope you've got them right, and to avoid `and`.

This:

```
exif2.width == 1250 and exif2.height == 833
```

is a lot harder to read and understand than:

```
(exif2.width == 1250) and (exif2.height == 833)
```

However because of precedence you also have to wrap the entire test in parenthesis:

```
(
  (exif2.width == 1250) and
  (exif2.height == 833)
)
```

which would work with the `=` assignment.

I eschew `and` though, and would use:

```
(
  (exif2.width == 1250) &&
  (exif2.height == 833)
)
```

because this really is a boolean test to AND the results of both tests. `&&` has a higher precedence than `and`, but, even so, I'd still write it on two lines with the parenthesis. I've been through too many interpreter and compiler battles to leave it to them to decide what happens when.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the order of operations now but I still am not quite sure why this order was not adhered to in the rails console?